# Client side validation for price(float) field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, coffeescript

I am using `Rails 3.2.13` and ruby `1.9.3p194`

I have added client side validation to allow user to enter only numbers[0-9] and decimal[.] in price field. My code is as follows:

**price.js.coffee**

```
  $("input").bind "keypress", (event) ->
    regex = new RegExp("^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$")
    key = String.fromCharCode((if not event.charCode then event.which else event.charCode))
    unless regex.test(key)
      false
```

**form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for :purchase, url: purchase_path, method: :post do |f|
= f.input :value, as: :integer, label: 'Amount',
  input_html: { min: "0.01", value: number_with_precision(precision: 2)}
```

Currently I am able to enter numbers in the textbox but I am unable to add a decimal point. I dont know where I am making a mistake. Any help is much appreciated.Thnx:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with your regex.

Try:

```
/^[0-9]\d*\.\d{2}$/
```

This will only allow prices ending in 2 digits after a decimal place e.g:

12.99,
13.00,
1.50,
0.30

but not

12.1,
.05,
15.999,
13

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply @rcandrzej but its not working for me, now its not accepting numbers as well.

Comment: Do you mean you can't type anything at all or you can't submit what you type/validation bounces your submission? If it's the latter, you need to explicitly type the entire price i.e. 12.00. For example, just typing 12 won't work. Check out my RegExr link: http://regexr.com?37j0u

Comment: if you are validating as you type, this is the regex you want to use:     ^[0-9]\d*(?:\.)*?(?:\d)?(?:\d)?$

Comment: this also not worked for me. this is same as what I have written in question. '^[0-9]\d*(?:\.)*?(?:\d)?(?:\d)?$ ' this only accepts number not decimal.